# UIScrollView in a UIViewController not scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll

I have an iPad app where I'm generating an image that I want to be 700X2000,  obviously larger then the height of the screen. Initially I had this image generated in a UIView, but now I re-wrote it to be a UIScrollView. I was assuming that the view would automatically vertically scroll to show the newly created image, but it does not - it simply cuts off at the bottom of the screen. 
What settings do I need to set for this to work? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the imageView as subview to the scrollView, and then set the contentSize of that scrollView to the image size.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. setting the content size isn't working at all - the actually line of code doesn't seem to have any affect. I turned off autolayout and it still doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Set it in viewdidappear

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `UIScrollView` scrolling is working.
Then you can scroll to some point in a scroll view with

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the UIScrollView content size, so if your image is 700x2000, you will need to use:

```
scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(700,2000);
```